# Requisição GET via AJAX só funciona dando um enter na barra de endereço

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, get

Bom dia,

É meio louco isso que está acontecendo, mas estou fazendo uma requisição via AJAX mandando um GET e o retorno está ok, está tudo certo, porém esse retorno é uma url que após efetuar a requisição deveria permitir acesso, porém só funciona se a url que estou requisitando via AJAX eu acessar na barra de endereços, não consigo entender qual lógica tem isso?

Exemplo:

```
 $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url  : 'http://services.teste.com/'+chaveAcesso,      
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(retorno) {
            if(retorno.url) {             
                console.log(retorno.url);
            }
        }
    });
```

A url de retorno está vindo porém ela deveria ter um privilégio de acesso e só funciona se eu efetuar a requisição pela barra de endereços colando esse endereço http://services.teste.com/'+chaveAcesso e dando um enter e não via ajax

Comment: O retorno é usado pra validar se a pessoa tem acesso é isso?

Comment: O retorno retorna uma url para gerar um acesso, por exemplo: urlretorno.com.br/novoidacesso e essa url urlretorno.com.br/novoidacesso está vindo, porém não funciona, mas se eu copiar a url da chamada do ajax e colar na barra de endereços ai a url de retorno urlretorno.com.br/novoidacesso irá funcionar :S, por exemplo ir na url e colar http://services.teste.com/chaveAcesso ai vai retornar urlretorno.com.br/novoidacesso funcionando, via ajax não funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma possibilidade é que o servidor que você está tentando executar o AJAX não aceita [`CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Answer (score 0):

Conforme apontado por @demarchisd, provavelmente seja um problema de CORS.

Uma maneira de resolver isso é fazer a requisição no lado do servidor e depois retornar com AJAX para a página desejada.

Por exemplo, em PHP vc pode ter um script (meuScript.php) que retorna o JSON usando a função `file_get_contents('http://url.desejada.com/')`.

Daí no java script vc faz:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url  : 'caminho/do/arquivo/meuScript.php',      
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(retorno) {
        if(retorno.url) {             
            console.log(retorno.url);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, vou implementar e logo mais retorno

Comment: Eu fiz com file_get_contents e também via curl para teste e não resolveu, vou entrar em contato com o pessoal da api e comentar sobre o cors pra ver se estão bloqueando o acesso